# Is this use pattern of virtual inheritance for "method injection" a known paradigm?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Yesterday, I came across this question: [forcing unqualified names to be dependent values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711871/forcing-unqualified-names-to-be-dependent-values/) Originally, it seemed like a very specific question related to broken VC++ behaviour, but while trying to solve it, I stumbled upon a use pattern of virtual inheritance I hadn't come across before (I will explain it in a second, after telling you the question I have). I found it interesting, so I looked for it on SO and google, but I couldn't find anything. Maybe, I just don't know the right name for it ("method injection" was one of my guesses) and it is actually widely known. This is also part of my question for the community: **Is this a common use pattern or a special case of another known paradigm? Do you see any problems/pitfalls that can be avoided by a different solution?**

The problem this pattern can solve is the following: Suppose you have a class `Morph` with a method `doWork()`. Within `doWork()`, several functions are called whose implementation is supposed to be selectable by the user (that's why the class is called `Morph`). Let's call those called functions chameleons (since the Morph class doesn't know what they will be in the end). One way to achieve this would of course be to make the chameleons virtual methods of the Morph class, so the user can derive from `Morph` and override selected methods. But what if the user is expected to use different combinations for selecting the implementation for different chameleons. Then, for every combination, a new class has to be defined. In addition, what if there are multiple `Morph`-like classes where the same functions are supposed to be chameleons? How can the user reuse the replacements she already implemented?

As for the "multiple classes have to be defined" problem, immediately, templates leap into one's mind. Can't the user select the chameleon implementations he wants by passing classes as template parameters which define the desired implementation? I.e. something like `Morph<ReplaceAB>` which should effectively replace the chameleons `A()` and `B()` in `doWork()` with some implementation, leaving the possible other chameleons, e.g., `C()`, untouched. With C++11 and variadic templates, even the combinations would not be a problem: `Morph<ReplaceAB, ReplaceC, WhateverMore...>` Well, that's exactly, what this pattern can do (see below for explanation):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// list all chameleons, could also be make some of them
// pure virtual, so a custom implementation is *required*.
struct Chameleons
{
  virtual void A() { cout << "Default A" << endl; }
  virtual void B() { cout << "Default B" << endl; }
  virtual void C() { cout << "Default C" << endl; }
};

// Chameleon implementations for A and B
struct ReplaceAB : virtual Chameleons
{
  virtual void A() { cout << "Alternative A" << endl; }
  virtual void B() { cout << "Alternative B" << endl; }
};

// Chameleon implementation for C
struct ReplaceC : virtual Chameleons
{
  virtual void C() { cout << "Alternative C" << endl; }
};

// A(), B(), C() in this class are made chameleons just by
// inheriting virtually from Chameleons
template <typename... Replace>
struct Morph : virtual Chameleons, Replace...
{
  void doWork() {
    A();
    B();
    C();
    cout << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  //default implementations
  Morph<>().doWork();
  //replace A and B
  Morph<ReplaceAB>().doWork();
  //replace C
  Morph<ReplaceC>().doWork();
  //replace A, B and C;
  Morph<ReplaceAB,ReplaceC>().doWork();
}
```

The output of which is the following:

```
Default A
Default B
Default C

Alternative A
Alternative B
Default C

Default A
Default B
Alternative C

Alternative A
Alternative B
Alternative C
```

Seeing this working solution only, the problem with the above idea is actually not so obvious: Couldn't `Morph` just derive from the classes specified as template parameters, so the chameleons `A()`, `B()` and `C()` are just taken from whatever `Morph` inherits from? This is actually not possible, because the calls to the chameleons do not depend on the template parameters, and such non-dependent names are not looked up in dependent inherited classes (try it, if you want). This means, we somehow have to achieve that the chameleon calls bind to something that can later be replaced by the desired implementation.

That's where the virtual inheritance comes in: By letting `Morph` inherit from `Chameleons` (non-dependent on the template parameters), the unqualified chameleon calls in `doWork()` bind to the virtual functions in `Chameleons`. Because `Morph` and the `Replacement` classes inherit virtually from `Chameleons`, there will only be a single `Chameleons` object in any `Morph` object, and the virtual function calls will be dispatched *at run-time* to the implementation in the most derived class, which we "smuggle in" through the templated inheritance. So, although the unqualified chameleon names in `doWork()` cannot be resolved to the desired implementation at compile time (in accordance with the standard), they can still be called by a layer of indirection through a virtual base class. Funny, huh? (Unless you tell me this is much easier to do in a different way or the pattern is widely known.)

Comment: Here goes for one of the longest questions (i hope) on SO

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry, I really wanted to explain the use pattern in detail. The question itself is not actually that long ;-)

Comment: OK, maybe I'm not quite getting it, what does this add over just taking a bunch of functors?

Comment: I don't quite see how you could do this using functors without implementing "setReplacement" methods for the structure holding the functors, which would come close to the original solution I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711871/forcing-unqualified-names-to-be-dependent-values). With the solution above, the compiler does everything for you and you can conveniently bundle the replacements according to your needs. Basically, you can make the function calls in an arbitrary function chameleons by just wrapping it with a Morph class.

Comment: So the idea is that given an otherwise unrelated function `void f(...){ /*code*/ A(); }`, you can c/p the code inside `f` to `Morph<...>::doWork(...){ /* code copied from f */ A(); }` and conveniently replace the calls to `A()` with arbitrary function calls *without changing the code you copied from `f()`*?

Comment: For example, yes (in there, it could even replace formerly global functions, as in the original question I cited). And if you want to do this with a function that is already a member of a class, you only have to add the virtual inheritance logic. No additional functor setters, no change in function arguments, etc. Also, you have some compile time checks that you wouldn't have with, e.g., functors: if you want to require a certain replacement, you can make the base class method pure virtual and the compiler will complain if you don't specify a replacement class for it.

Comment: Neat.  You can get the same kind of functionality (and better compile time optimisation) using policies and templates (as explained in Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu).

Comment: "deadly diamond of death" comes to mind

Comment: @JarkkoL: Of course, it comes to mind because this is the problem virtual inheritance usually solves. The funny thing here is that virtual inheritance is strictly necessary to make it work. You cannot work around it with a "better design" as is sometimes suggested in other cases. Can you specify why you think the DDD can hit you in this case? I  don't see the problem.

Comment: @Oguk Virtual inheritance doesn't solve DDD but causes it (that's where the name comes from - the diamond shape of the inheritance hierarchy). The problem occurs when you have ReplaceAB and ReplaceBC and try to combine them.

Comment: @JarkkoL: Well, I think that is a matter of definition... In many questions here on SO, virtual inheritance is called the "solution" to the problem, because the diamond in the inheritance diagram is there no matter whether you use virtual inheritance or not (don't confuse classes with objects). But _with_ virtual inheritance, your actual objects more closely resemble that diamond-shaped diagram, because there are is just one common base class object (just as there is only one common base class in the inheritance diagram).

Comment: @JarkkoL: But I see the limitation (not, however, that it is in anyway _caused_ by virtual inheritance): You cannot have overlapping sets of replacements in two replacement classes. The compiler would complain about ambiguity in this case (which, on the other hand, is nice compared to the functor solution suggested by T.C., where you could silently replace and already replaced function if you don't implement a separate check for it).

Comment: @Oguk You can't derive overlapping implementations with virtual inheritance, while you can without => causes it. With virtual inheritance you actually have to resolve the ambiguity by implementing the offending function in the Morph class which you can't do, AFAIK. Though I don't know if there's any way to solve it without either. I'm not a big fan of using MI due to various issues it has but would rather look for other kind of solution. It may seem like this is a manageable issue with your simple example and that you could avoid overlaps but it can become quite a tangled mess IME.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works fine. Virtual inheritance avoids ambiguity errors. Variadic template brings elegant instantiation syntax. Instead of something like:

```
 class M1 : public ReplaceAB, ReplaceC {} i1;
 i1.doWork();
```

you have just one line:

```
Morph<ReplaceAB, ReplaceC>().doWork();
```

From my point of view the proposed pattern is not common. A the same time, is this something really new? Well, there are millions and millions lines of code... The chance that somebody used something similar is not zero at all. Most likely you will never know this for sure.